# Логика jquery на ванильный javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Есть логика, написанная на jquery. Я немного увлекся этим jquery в последнее время, и подзабыл некоторые моменты js. У меня пока не совсем получается преобразовать свою логику jquery на js. Я представлю код на jquery и на js. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что я делаю не так?! Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height_nav = $(".nav").height();
    if (top >= height_nav+22) {
      $(".sidebar").css('top', 0);
    } else {
      $(".sidebar").css('top', height_nav-top+22);
    }  
       
});
```

js:

```
var top = window.scrollTop();
var height_nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav').scrollHeight;
var sidebar_top = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar');

if (top >= height_nav+22) {
      sidebar_top.style.top = 0;
} else {
      sidebar_top.style.top = height_nav-top+22;
}
```

Comment: Надо указать  `px` в конце css свойств. И `window.scrollTop` это не функция

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    let top = window.pageYOffset;
    let height_nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0].scrollHeight;
    let sidebar_top = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];

    if (top >= (height_nav + 22)) {
      sidebar_top.style.top = 0 + 'px' ;
    } else {
      sidebar_top.style.top = (height_nav - (top + 22)) + 'px' ;
    } 
});
```

Попробуй так

Comment: пишет -  `"Uncaught TypeError: window.scrollTop is not a function"`

Comment: прописал вот так - `top = Window.scrollY`, теперь пишет - `Cannot set property 'top' of undefined"`

Comment: let top = window.pageYOffset можно так

Comment: вот что в ответ `SyntaxError: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name"`

Comment: два раза let был написан. теперь все так же ошибка `Cannot set property 'top' of undefined"`   при `top = window.pageYOffset`

Comment: добавил вот так - `let sidebar_top = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];` Ошибка пропала, но логика не выполняется.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0] тоже нужно добавить

Comment: Заработало, спасибо)